# Airflow:permission error is coming when i am running with docker

Tags: airflow

When i am running the docker up airflow-init command the following error is coming

```
airflow-init_1       | error: failed switching to "airflow": operation not permitted
airflow-init_1       |
airflow-init_1       | ERROR!!! Too old Airflow version !
airflow-init_1       | The minimum Airflow version supported 2.2.0. Only use this or higher!
airflow-init_1       |
docker_airflow-init_1 exited with code 1
```

even i included the latest image of airflow in docker-compose.yml file, please do help.

Comment: Can you share the contents of your `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Are you also building your own docker container image? If so, please also share contents of your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue is that the [base Airflow docker-compose.yaml](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.4.0/docker-compose.yaml) contains a command for airflow-init that includes `gosu airflow airflow version`. The problem is, `whoami` showed I was already running as the user `airflow`, while `gosu` is only used for switching from root to less privileges. I was not able to figure out the reason for the different user, but removing the `gosu airflow` from that command fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear to me exactly how @Noumenon intends to modify the bash variable definition below:

```
airflow_version=$$(AIRFLOW__LOGGING__LOGGING_LEVEL=INFO && gosu airflow airflow version)
```

but it did work if i hard-coded the version:

```
airflow_version=2.5.3
```